# Using Anypoint Access Management - Mulesoft APIs

Tags: api, mule

Good morning I am using internal mulesoft Access Management APIs [API Reference](https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/apiplatform/anypoint-platform/#/portals/organizations/68ef9520-24e9-4cf2-b2f5-620025690913/apis/11270/versions/11646/pages/11245). I have successfully setup my postman to get the security token after login, and even executed successfully the /api/users/me. However, regardless of the access provided to the connection/login user, i can't get the full list of users (/api/users), receiving a Not authorized error. Let me explain the context. We are running on a federated platform, so we can't manage the users registration from the console, but need to wait until they login through SSO the first time to grant access to the correspondent business group and role. There is a complain as the users need to send the admin a note letting know of their successful first login, and afterwards wait to receive the access to the business group. After they login for the first time, their profiles are created in the root org. You can see them only when you are in the master organization. However, you can't get their new user id when you request a list of users of this master organization (/api/organizations/{orgId}/users). We are looking to execute this /api/users in a batch app that runs periodically and do a cross verification to get the users not associated to any orgid or role. This way we can avoid the requirement of the user sending a note to the admin. When I execute the /accounts/api/users, (API Call), we receive a 401 Unauthorized response, despite the token is correct as it is working fine with the others APIs. there is no mention of any other parameter or requirement in the API reference.

Please advise what can be done to solve this authorization error and complete our app. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue but figured it out.

Instead of calling /api/users, you should be calling

```
https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/accounts/api/organizations/{orgId}/members
```

to get a list of users